# DependencyProperty binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

My objective here is to disable and enabled some items on a GUI based on the value of a flag that will be changed during execution in the code behind for the window.  I've set up a DependencyProperty to accomplish this. I believe that all I have to do is bind the this property to the appropriate "IsEnabled" properties and everything should work.  Something is not hooking up properly so nothing is happening. Am I missing some syntax here or something?

Here is the binding in WPF (MainWindow.xaml):

```
<MenuItem Name="LoggingMenuItem" Header="_Logging" IsCheckable="True" Checked="LoggingMenuItem_Checked" IsEnabled="{Binding  ElementName=IsMonitoring}" />
```

Here is the declaration of the "IsMonitoring" Property in the code behind (MainWindow.xaml.cs):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMonitoringProperty = 
   DependencyProperty.Register("IsMonitoring", typeof(Boolean), typeof(Window));

public bool IsMonitoring
{
   get { return (bool)GetValue(IsMonitoringProperty); }
   set { SetValue(IsMonitoringProperty, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your binding is not configured correctly. The ElementName attribute should point to an "Element" (that is control) within the Window and you should use the Path attribute to specify the property name.

In your case, you want to give the Window a name to use. I tend to use the name "this" but of course it could be whatever you want.

```
<Window x:Name="this"
        ...
        >
    ...
    <MenuItem IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=IsMonitoring}" />
    ...
</Window>
```

Comment: FYI, this worked but I had to add quotes to "this" to get it to compile like such 'x:Name="this"'.  This is interesting though, from the code behind I'm able to access elements and properties just by name with no problem.  The same is true within the WPF code when I'm binding to 'other' UI items that also declared in the WPF, there is no problem.  So why is it a special case when I try to access items declared in the code behind from WPF code?

Comment: In that case Ultratrunks, don't forget to mark it as the answer

Comment: @Ultratrunks - The bindings will look at properties within the DataContext for the control by default (usually your "View Model"). In your case, you want to look at the property on the control itself.